# Convert string to URI C++

Tags: c++, url, visual-c++

My issue is simple. I have a string:

```
std::string PATH = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(FBD->SelectedPath);
```

And I want to convert it into a URI, so I can use it here:

```
this->FILE_BROWSER->Url = // Converted URI goes here.
```

I have no idea how to do this, even after searching through every single System::Uri method.

I've searched this up on the internet and I've only seen answers for Java and C#, any help for C++ is appreciated.

Comment: A URI is just a string in a specific format: `<schema>://<Host | Domain>/<Path>` What are you trying to convert exactly and what is the example from Java (or C#) that you are referring to?

Comment: In C# it looks like this:

FILE_BROWSER.Url = new Uri(FBD.SelectedPath);

Just trying to figure out how do that in C++.

Comment: You are looking for a URI class that you can then use to accesses objects on the web. Nothing like that exists in the standard for C++.